# complex variables, finding the identity

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\sin(\theta)+ \sin (2\theta)+\ldots+\sin(n\theta).$$

Find the identity? Set $z=e^{i\theta}$.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to where to start/go from.

So far I have

$$\frac{1-e^{i\theta(n+1)}}{1-e^{i\theta}}.$$

And I am stuck as to where to go from here.

Comment: "Find the identity"? The identity of **what** ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to evaluate this sum?

Comment: find the identity(generalized function) for sin(theta)+ sin (2*theta)+...+sin(ntheta)

Comment: yes @user112495

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^ne^{ki\theta}=e^{i\theta}\frac{e^{ni\theta}-1}{e^{i\theta}-1}=\left(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\right)\frac{\cos n\theta-1+i\sin n\theta}{\cos\theta-1+i\sin\theta}$$

Find now real and imaginary parts and complete.

Comment: thank you for the start but just wondering why the 1 changed to -1 and the e^(itheta) outside

Comment: shouldnt it be e^itheta(e^(-itheta) - e^(itheta*n)/(1-e^(itheta))?

Comment: @O No, it is as I wrote it.

Comment: but the partial sum of 1 + z + z^2 + ... = (1-z^(n+1))/(1-z). I'd really appreciate if you could point where I am wrong. In the above solution you gave though, you multiplied by a minus. Can't I still use e^itheta(e^(-itheta) - e^(itheta*n)/(1-e^(itheta))?!

Comment: @okocj where do you take that minus in the exponent from?! And also pay attention to the fact that $$\frac{a-1}{b-1}=\frac{1-a}{1-b}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\sin(k\theta)
&=\frac1{2i}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(e^{ik\theta}-e^{-ik\theta}\right)\tag{1}\\
&=\frac1{2i}\left(\frac{e^{i(n+1)\theta}-e^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}-1}
-\frac{e^{-i(n+1)\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{e^{-i\theta}-1}\right)\tag{2}\\
&=\frac1{2i}\left(\frac{e^{i(n+1/2)\theta}-e^{i\theta/2}}{e^{i\theta/2}-e^{-i\theta/2}}
-\frac{e^{-i(n+1/2)\theta}-e^{-i\theta/2}}{e^{-i\theta/2}-e^{i\theta/2}}\right)\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: write $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}2$
$(2)$: sum of a geometric series
$(3)$: adjust to make the denominators similar

---

Here is the rest
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\sin(k\theta)
&=\frac1{2i}\left(\frac{e^{i(n+1/2)\theta}-e^{i\theta/2}}{e^{i\theta/2}-e^{-i\theta/2}}
-\frac{e^{-i(n+1/2)\theta}-e^{-i\theta/2}}{e^{-i\theta/2}-e^{i\theta/2}}\right)\\
&=\frac1{2i}\left(\frac{e^{i(n+1/2)\theta}+e^{-i(n+1/2)\theta}}{e^{i\theta/2}-e^{-i\theta/2}}
-\frac{e^{i\theta/2}+e^{-i\theta/2}}{e^{i\theta/2}-e^{-i\theta/2}}\right)\\
&=\frac1{2i}\left(\frac{2\cos((n+1/2)\theta)}{2i\sin(\theta/2)}
-\frac{2\cos(\theta/2)}{2i\sin(\theta/2)}\right)\\
&=\frac{\cos(\theta/2)-\cos((2n+1)\theta/2)}{2\sin(\theta/2)}\\
&=\frac{\sin((n+1)\theta/2)\sin(n\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: thanks alot a lot got it using this approach but the numerator was very messy...and my answer was (sin((n+1)/2)*theta)*(cosntheta/2))/sin(theta/2)

Comment: The answer I got from $(3)$ was $$\frac{\cos(\theta/2)-\cos((2n+1)\theta/2)}{2\sin(\theta/2)} =\frac{\sin((n+1)\theta/2)\sin(n\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)}$$

Comment: @okocj: since you seem to have done the work with a small error, I will finish the answer.